# How to store rxjs emitted values?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to wrap my head around rxjs.
I have made an angular service that emits and listens to boolean values indicating that an async operation has started, and then ended.

```
export class UpdateScriptRunningEventService {
  private UpdateScriptRunningEvent = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  emit(flag: boolean) {this.UpdateScriptRunningEvent.next(flag);}
  listen(): Observable<any> { return this.UpdateScriptRunningEvent.asObservable() }
}
```

it works well, but now I would like to be able to find out that all async operations have ended. So I would like to store those emitted boolean values, in order to count the true and false values. If they are is the same number, then it indicated that all async operations have ended, and subsequently the store can be emptied.

Any pointer in that direction is much appreciated.

EDIT: thanks a lot for the indications so far. I am also thinking about the case where an async would fail. In my case I cannot consider a failed operations as ended. In order to not stay stuck in a "not all operations ended" state, so the UI would have to propose "retry" button. If the retry is successful then it reaches the "all ended" state.

Comment: BehaviorSubject only ever returns its most recent value. You should probably use ReplaySubject https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/replaysubject.html

Comment: ok I read a little bit about ReplaySubject and if I understand right, subscriber created at startup will shot the latest value (same as the current code), and newly created subscriber shout the whole stored sequence. So with that I could do a function that creates a new subscriber in order to get the whole history and process it to know if all requests have ended. Nice. Now to "empty" the store I am not sure, it seems that I have to override it with a new ReplaySubject in order to get an empty store. Is that right ?

Comment: I will try all this tomorrow morning once I am back at work, thanks both altu and @Will Alexander. I will give then some feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an Observable which watches the base Subject and progressively adds values (`true` as `1` and `false` as `-1`), which then emits every time the total hits zero:

```js
const allOpsDone$ = this.updateService.listen().pipe(
  map(result => result ? 1 : -1), // turn true into 1 and false into -1
  scan((accumulated, current) => accumulated + current, 0), // sum over time
  filter(result => result === 0), // only emit results where result === 0
  map(() => true) // optional, emits value of true when result is 0
);
```

Comment: Mmmh. Casting boolean to 1/-1 seems a nice idea, since it make the calculation of state zero "all async operations ended" possible. Also here if I understand right, it does not store past values, but simply emits when the new total is zero. Now for the case of the "retry" button (see my edit). It seems that to handle I would need to use an object of states instead of booleans, so that the accumulator can contain also the information that a request failed.

Comment: If you want to move into more complex state management, I'd recommend using something like NgRx. That way, you can simple use an application store to resolve everything you need.

Comment: I ended up with the following, based on your idea :
   allDone(): Observable<boolean>{
    return this.listen().pipe(
      map(result => result ? 1 : -1), // cast booleans to 1 / -1
      scan((accumulated, current) => (accumulated + current > 0) ? accumulated + current : 0, 0), // sum over time
      map((sum) => sum === 0)
    );
  }

Comment: Glad I could help :)